# Storing date time in mysql table

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am using `datetime` field for storing date and time in table

default it stores in :   12/3/2010 3:41:37` PM  Format.

is there any way to store time in `12/3/2010 15:41`

I don't want to store second and waht to store hrs in 24 hr format.

Help me please in this matter.

Answer (score 5):

The format in which you store it is irrelevant.  It's a datetime datatype and the database sees it as such.  Formatting it a certain way is a function of display.  You can either format it in your SQL (which is probably messy), or via whatever programming language you're using.  Most have some dateFormat() functions available to them.

Comment: +1. A date is a date. Though you could choose to strip seconds before you store the value, or you could use a trigger to do that. This still won't affect the notation in which the date is displayed (it will show 12/3/2010 3:41:00 PM), but you know that the values are stripped. This might improve performance if you need your queries to be grouped by minutes. But that's the only reason I can think of for rounding the value, and I wouldn't round them at all, unless the performance really becomes an issue.

Comment: Thanks charliegriefer & GolezTrol : Followed u and It solved my problem.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have used these functions:

```
left(date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%d %T'),17)
```

Now it's working.